# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Key "likeCount" has no data

Tags: ios, swift, parse.com, uibutton

Подскажите ! не могу сохранить в ячейки кол-во лайков. Сервер Parse. Выдает такую ошибку.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Key "likeCount" has no
>   data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.'

Может кто нибудь подсказать как правильно записать?

```
let saveCount = InfoMy(withoutDataWithObjectId: "PIorJ43dRq")
        var click = saveCount.likeCount
        click += 1
        saveCount.setObject(click, forKey: "likeCount")

        saveCount.saveInBackground()
```

Comment: я бы попробовал Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value

Comment: Спасибо разобрался! Если сможете подтвердите мой вопрос ! Я нашел как исправить!

Answer (score 0):

Вот таким методом Решил проблему на свою ошибку!

```
  let objectInfo = InfoMy(withoutDataWithClassName: "InfoMy", objectId: "PIorJ43dRq")
       objectInfo.incrementKey("likeCount", byAmount: 1)


        objectInfo.saveInBackground {  (object, error) in
            if  error == nil {
                print("success")


            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })

            }
        }
```